# Bind typedef function

Tags: c++

I have bind function to std::function. Function declaration:

```
typedef HGLRC (WINAPI * PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC) (HDC hDC, HGLRC hShareContext, const int *attribList);
```

My code load function and bind:

```
std::function<PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC> function;
auto func = reinterpret_cast<PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC>(getAnyGLFuncAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB"));
function = func;
```

Line `function = func;` causes a compilation error. Error:

```
Error (active)  E0349   no operator "=" matches these operands  
operand types are: std::function<PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC> = PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC
```

I do not understand why the code is not working. If I declared function using using, then all working:

```
using WglCreateContextAttribsARB = HGLRC (WINAPI *) (HDC hDC, HGLRC hShareContext, const int *attribList);
```

Comment: Why are you using `std::bind` when you're not binding any arguments? `function = func;` should work, as far as I know.

Comment: @molbdnilo sorry, but `function = func;` too not working, Forgot to write about it. Error: (operator= no found(std::function = PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC))

Comment: Please copy and paste your error messages into the question. Don't rephrase them.

Comment: @molbdnilo done

Comment: @TheGoldKnight23 I am trying to make this: `Your casting func to type PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC then trying to assign it to a function object which takes PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC as an argument`

Comment: The argument to `std::function` is supposed to be a function type, but `PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC` is a *pointer*-to-function type. If you define `typedef HGLRC (WINAPI FNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC) (HDC hDC, HGLRC hShareContext, const int *attribList);` (without the pointer), does `function = reinterpret_cast<FNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC *>(...);` work? I don't know why the `using` version would work though; that should have the same problem.

Comment: @HTNW my problem is that I cannot change the type of function :)

Comment: @Range Then `std::remove_pointer_t<PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your problems is that you are trying to create an `std::function` object out of only its return type. The template calls for a full function type to be passed so you need to specify what it takes as well.

Your assignment error comes from trying to assign an `std::function` which is templated (invalidly) to return `PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC` to a `PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC`.

You do this here:

```cpp
std::function<PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC> function = reinterpret_cast<PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC>(...);
```

It fails as you cannot (unsuprisingly) assign an object meant to represent a function to the value that it returns. If you want to copy (or move) `FNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC` to a `std::function` then make `FNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC` an `std::function` as well. If thats not an option (for example if its an unmodifiable API) you *could* use a lambda to wrap the C style function.

If you want to use a `std::function` you must provide a valid type for it by specifying both its return type and its parameters. Like so

```cpp
std::function<FNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC()> func;
```

(That function will take no arguments)

Side note: there are very few contexts where C function pointers should be used, `std::function` does have some overhead due to the type erasure but 99% of the time its not going to be significant. Also I am not sure what you mean when you say that `using` fixes the problem. It shouldn't do (as far as I can see, although it may be typedef's weirdness with templates) unless you've used different code you have not shown in your question.

Comment: "Your problem is that you have declared your `std::function` to return a value of `PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC`" Does it? Since `PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC` isn't a function type, I don't believe `std::function<PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC>` is a valid specialization that does *anything*.

Comment: Exactly. That's not a function type. Go test it: just the declaration `std::function<void (*)()> oops;` [raises an error](https://godbolt.org/z/o7XXJV). `std::function` takes a function type, so to make my example work, it's supposed to be `std::function<void ()>`. Similarly, this question calls for `std::function<HGLRC (WINAPI)(HDC, HGLRC, int const*)>`, or `std::function<std::remove_pointer_t<PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC>>`.

Comment: @HTNW Oh... I feel dumb, i'll update my answer and bang my head against the wall a few times as I try and work out how a pointer to a function is a function type